# Convert color image into black and white using java created from scratch

Tags: java, image-processing, java-8, bufferedimage, graphics2d

I want to convert my picture from colored to Black and white which seems to be created from scratch.
Here is the code which i tried as described on the different post:

```
    BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/***/Documents/Photograph.jpg"));
    ColorConvertOp op = 
        new ColorConvertOp(ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_GRAY), null);
    ImageIO.write(bi, "PNG", new File("/Users/bng/Documents/rendered2.png"));
    op.filter(bi, bi);
```

But still my image is not converted to the Black and white. Additionally, this code is increasing the rendered2.png image size to 10 folds. 
Also, it would be great if i could find some Java 8 way of doing this.
Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd be more specific on the result you want to have. A black and white image has only two colors, also called binary image. A grayscale image (which you try to create with the ColorSpace.CS_GRAY) has more colors than two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have to find RGB of the existing colors of the image you want to change it.
2. Fyi, you want to change it as white RGB value is (255,255,255) and for black RGB value is (0,0,0)
3. Following method easily do the color change if you apply correct way of your requirement

   ```
   private BufferedImage changeColor(BufferedImage image, int srcColor, int replaceColor)
   {
       BufferedImage destImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
       Graphics2D g = destImage.createGraphics();
       g.drawImage(image, null, 0, 0);
       g.dispose();


       for (int width = 0; width < image.getWidth(); width++)
       {
           for (int height = 0; height < image.getHeight(); height++)
           {

              if (destImage.getRGB(width, height) == srcColor)
               {
                  destImage.setRGB(width, height, replaceColor);
               }

           }
       }

       return destImage;
   }
   ```

Comment: This changed the image to black and white, but does not make it as made from scratch.

Comment: you have to just create image, check online multiple sources available.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code which worked for me:

```
    BufferedImage input = ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/bng/Documents/Photograph.jpg"));
    // Create a black-and-white image of the same size.
    BufferedImage im = new BufferedImage(input.getWidth(), input.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);
    // Get the graphics context for the black-and-white image.
    Graphics2D g2d = im.createGraphics();
    // Render the input image on it.
    g2d.drawImage(input, 0, 0, null);
    // Store the resulting image using the PNG format.
    ImageIO.write(im, "PNG", new File("/Users/bng/Documents/rendered.png"));
```

It was BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY which provided me the exact solution.
Lokking for the Java 8 Version for above code.

Comment: how does that create a grayscale (black/white) image?

Comment: It is TYPE_BYTE_BINARY which gives its black and white color as specified "nt java.awt.image.BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY = 12 [0xc]

Represents an opaque byte-packed 1, 2, or 4 bit image. The image has an IndexColorModel without alpha. When this type is used as the imageType argument to the BufferedImage constructor that takes an imageType argument but no ColorModel argument, a 1-bit image is created with an IndexColorModel with two colors in the default sRGB ColorSpace: {0, 0, 0} and {255, 255, 255}."

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the [`ColorConvertOp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/ColorConvertOp.html#filter(java.awt.image.BufferedImage,%20java.awt.image.BufferedImage)) in a proper way:

1. create Source image
2. apply filter
3. save dest

example:

```
BufferedImage src = ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/***/Documents/Photograph.jpg"));

ColorConvertOp op = 
    new ColorConvertOp(ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_GRAY), null);
BufferedImage dest = op.filter(src, null);

ImageIO.write(dest, "PNG", new File("/Users/bng/Documents/rendered2.png"));
```

src:
[image]

dest:
[image]

Comment: if you like **one-liners** you can do  `ImageIO.write(new ColorConvertOp(ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_GRAY), null).filter(ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/***/Documents/Photograph.jpg")), null), "PNG", new File("/Users/bng/Documents/rendered2.png"));`

Comment: Your one liner is good. Somehow does not convert image as being made from scratch. Searching for some other options.

Comment: the `ColorSpace.CS_GRAY` does create a **gray-scale** image not a **black&white** image...

Comment: @Karan Verma: it is the original code of your question which refers to `ColorSpace.CS_GRAY`. If you don’t want a grayscale image, it’s your problem.